# R - Why is my code for integrals not working unless the input length is exactly 15?

Tags: r

I have this code:

```
itc_1 <- function(t, x) {
  subout_1 <- dlnorm(t, 2.72 - x, 0.52)
  return(subout_1)
}

itc_2 <- function(t, x) {
  subout_2 <- 1 - plnorm(t, 2.72 - x, 0.52)
  return(subout_2)
}

itc_3 <- function(x, t) {
  subout_3 <- grad(itc_2, x = x, t = t)
  return(subout_3)
}

itc_4 <- function(t, x) {
  subout_4 <- -itc_3(x, t) * itc_2(t, x)
  return(subout_4)
}

integrate(f = itc_4, lower = 0, upper = Inf, x = seq(-2, 2, length.out = 15))
```

This gives out the error the `integral is probably divergent`, but this is not the focus of my post, because in any case I have to tweak some values later.

This question is about why the error message changes when the length of `x` in the `integrate` function is anything else other than 15. Let's just modify the last line and see what the output is:

```
integrate(f = itc_4, lower = 0, upper = Inf, x = seq(-2, 2, length.out = 14))

Error in grad.default(itc_2, x = x, t = t) :
grad assumes a scalar valued function.
```

Upon clicking on the "Rerun with debug", I discovered that the output of the function `itc_2` at one point has length 15, and the integration stops if the length of the function does not match the length of the input given here.

However, I am not sure why exactly would that output have a length of 15. I didn't anywhere specify any lengths of objects. Any help with this would be appreciated.

To clarify the steps of what I am doing, I will write out this list:

1. Calculate the PDF of the lognormal distribution, where `t` is the individual value and `x` is a component of the mean, which is being subtracted from 2.72
2. Calculate 1 - CDF of the lognormal distribution
3. Calculate the partial derivative of the CDF of the lognormal distribution with respect to x
4. Multiply the negative partial derivative with the 1 - CDF
5. Integrate the result across values of t ranging from 0 to infinity

Comment: The function `grad` needs a function which returns either a scalar (one value) or a vector the length of the vector `grad` is applied to. Do you perhaps have `t` != 15 defined in your global environment (as you don't specify `t` in the arguments of `integrate`) so that `itc_2` returns a value of length other than 15 which doesn't match `x`s length in your `grad` call and thus raises the error?

Comment: I suspect I-O is right - you arent submitting any value for `t` to `integrate`, and your family of functions should throw an error because there's no default value for `t` specified.